# How do I make an animated geographic map in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, animation, dictionary

We're trying to map the sizes of lakes over time.  We've gotten it to work mostly, the issue is that we are clearing and re-drawing the lakes every year, but it looks weird because the lakes are drawn one at a time each year.  It would be great if we could clear the screen, draw everything, and THEN update the display, instead of watching the lakes re-draw over every year.  Any ideas?  Here's our code

```
clear all; close all; clc;

%%Plot the map of Wisconsin
wi = shaperead('usastatehi', 'UseGeoCoords', true,'Selector',{@(name)...
    strcmpi(name,'Wisconsin'), 'Name'});
axesm('mercator','MapLatLimit',[42.4569,47.0448],'MapLonLimit',[-92.9644,...
    -86.6662])

geoshow(wi,'FaceColor','white')

%%Plot the lake area changes through the years
load lakearea.mat
load lakeloc.mat

lat_lake = lakeloc(1,:);
lon_lake = lakeloc(2,:);
years =29;
numlake =12;
for j = 1:1:years
    clma
    geoshow(wi,'FaceColor','white')
    lake_area = lakearea(j,2:13);
    for i=1:1:numlake
        if lake_area(i) ~= 0
            scatterm(lat_lake(i),lon_lake(i),lake_area(i)/(10^4),'filled')
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The following solution may work: Hide the figure: `set(gcf, 'Visible', 'off')`. Draw images on invisible figure. Use `getimage` to get image data. Restore visibility, and show images frame by frame.